# Testing a condition on every element of a matrix

Tags: r

I want to test whether every element of data frame is greater than 0. If it is greater than zero it would we will be "buy" otherwise "sell". I used sapply. It allocated every value "sell". I used following code. Also recommend for loop solution.

```
df1<-sapply(df,function(x) ifelse(x>0,yes="buy",no="sell"))
```

Comment: If you are using `matrix`, don't use `sapply`, `df[] <- c("sell", "buy")[(df >0) + 1]`

Comment: @akrun that solve my purpose. But tell me why we used +1 at last

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a `matrix` (or even `data.frame`), create a logical matrix by using the comparison operator.  This gives a `TRUE/FALSE` logical matrix which is of value 1/0.  If we add 1 to it, it changes to `2/1` and based on that index, we can replace values (in `R`, indexing starts from 1)

```
df[] <- c("sell", "buy")[(df >0) + 1]
```

---

Also, in the comments, it was recommended not to use `sapply` on `matrix` as `matrix` is a `vector` with `dim` attributes and the unit element is a single element (in `data.frame`, the unit is a column - so if we use `sapply/lapply`, it loops through columns).  Here, it loops through element of the `matrix`.  So, it may not be efficient.  For `matrix`, `apply` with `MARGIN`can be used

```
df[] <- apply(df, 2, FUN = function(x) ifelse(x > 0, "sell", "buy"))
```

Comment: @ Thanks for clarification